# What are the new percent macros in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I converted a 2008 C++ project to 2012 and it added some new thing to Additional Include Directories in project properties:

```
$(DXSDK_DIR)\Include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

What does it do and what is the proper name to google for it?

Comment: check [this link](http://takinginitiative.net/2010/07/02/setting-up-the-directx-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010/), it is not vs 2008 to 2012 conversion related but for 2008 to 2010 but hope this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from MSVC10, you may use [Property Sheets](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224030000/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx) to alter settings for multiple projects `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` refers to the include directories that you project inherits from Property Sheets.

Comment: Typo: "multiply" should probably be "multiple"?